# Changing a list of integers into strings and keeping each digit

Tags: python, string, list, int

I have a list of lists of ints that looks like this:

```
paystring[:3]
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2],
 [2, 2, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I need to convert these into one integer so

```
100000002212
225543333322
000000000000
```

I tried this:

```
x = []
for row in paystring:
    x.append(int("".join(map(str, row))))
```

But for `x[:3]` I get

```
[100000002212, 225543333322, 0]
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: 0 and 000000000000 are the same integer, if you want to keep the leading zeroes leave it as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct modification from your code would be this:

```
x = []
for row in paystring:
    x.append(str("".join(map(str, row))))
```

Transforming into `str` instead of `int`

Otherwise it will not keep the `0s`

Comment: Thank you one problem though is when I do this se = pd.Series(x)
df['Paystring'] = se.values in the excel file I still get 1 zero for the third row. Do you know how to fix that problem?

Comment: If you do something like df['Paystring'] = se.values;df['Paystring'].to_csv('test.csv'); on the test.csv file, it does keep all the digits. The problem might be when importing into excel

Answer (score 0):

One way using `list-comprehension`

```
lst = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2],
        [2, 2, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

[''.join(map(str,l)) for l in lst]
#['100000002212', '225543333322', '000000000000']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use format function in python like below :

```
print('{0:012d}'.format(0))
```

Output:

```
000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will fix the problem of the zero's being added together.

```
paystring=[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2],
          [2, 2, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

strings = []
for el in paystring:
    string = ""
    for number in el:
        string+= str(number)
    strings.append(string)
print(strings)
```

It will print this:
['100000002212', '225543333322', '000000000000']

Answer (score -1):

Strictly speaking there is no number like *000000000* we write it as *0*.

If you really want leading 0s dont convert the string to integer with `int()`